# Where to find the Public Water System's companies' annual survey report?

Tags: usa

We are looking for the aggregate data for all US water companies' annual survey. This may also be called Consumer Confidence Report.

We are looking for the detailed findings like the hardness of the water or the pH level.

Comment: usgs has water data on the national level, but not individual company data; i'm not aware of any source that is comprehensive in this sense. its been my experience that each company publishes their individual reports (if they do it at all) on their own sites. seems like there is no standardization, so even if you do get to collect multiple reports from different sources, putting them together is a daunting task.